# JSF h:selectOneMenu is never set even when using f:ajax

Tags: jsf, binding

I want to implement a filtering facility in a JSF web application as follows:  The users can add as many filters as  they want.  They can also delete them.  So I am having a dataTable of filters.  Each row consists of one h:selectOneMenu which has an ajax “change” event in order to make a second h:selectOneMenu visible in the same row.  The options of the second h:selectOneMenu are calculated dynamically according to the selected option of the first.

The problem is that the value of second h:selectOneMenu is never set to the back-end object even if I added an ajax event.  However the value of the first h:selectOneMenu is set.

I have the following fragment of code in an .xhtml page:

```
<h:form id="filterForm">
    <h:dataTable id="filterTable" value="#{filterManager.filters}" var="filter">
        <h:column>
            <h:outputLabel value="#{msgs.filterBy}:" for="availableFilters" />
            <h:selectOneMenu id="availableFilters" value="#{filter.filter}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{filterManager.getProperties(typeSelector.typeSelected)}" />
                <f:ajax event="change" render=":filterForm" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <h:panelGroup id="filterValuesPanel" >
                <h:outputLabel value="#{msgs.value}:" for="filterValues" rendered="#{!filter.filterEmpty}" />
                <h:selectOneMenu value="#{filter.value}" id="filterValues" rendered="#{!filter.filterEmpty}" >
                    <f:selectItems value="#{filterManager.getPossibleAnswers(filter)}" />
                    <f:ajax event="change" render=":filterForm" />
                </h:selectOneMenu>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <h:commandButton value="#{msgs.delete}" title="#{msgs.deleteFilter}">
                <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{filterManager.removeFilter(filter)}" render=":filterForm" />
            </h:commandButton>
        </h:column>

    </h:dataTable>

    <h:commandButton value="#{msgs.addNewFilter}">
        <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{filterManager.addNewFilter}" render=":filterForm" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

I have a bean called “FilterManager” which has a ViewScoped.  Important parts are shown below:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class FilterManager implements Serializable {

    private List<Filter> filters; // it has a getter
    private int currentFilterId;

    public void addNewFilter(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
        this.currentFilterId++;
        this.filters.add(Filter.getEmptyFilter(this.currentFilterId));
    }

    public void removeFilter(Filter filter) {
        this.filters.remove(filter);
    }

...

}
```

The Filter class is a normal class (not a bean) and is shown below:

```
public class Filter implements Serializable {

    private int id;       
    private String filter;
    private String value;


    public String getFilter() {
        return filter;
    }


    public void setFilter(String theFilter) {
        if (theFilter != null && !theFilter.isEmpty())
            this.filter = theFilter;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }


    public void setValue(String theValue) {
        this.value = theValue;
    }

    public boolean isFilterEmpty() {
        return this.filter == null || this.filter.isEmpty();
    }
...

}
```

Notice that TypeSelector is a SessionScoped bean which has a typeSelected property along with getter and setter.

The problem is: filter.filter is set correctly whereas filter.value is never set.  I can't find the problem so I need your help please.  Apologies for all this code but I needed to provide you with all the necessary details.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please Edit your question.. no body would ever see this looonnggg question buddy!

Comment: @NGH Thanks for the suggestion.  I removed some code.  The think is that since I don't know where the issue is I put the part of code which I believe is relevant to the problem.

Comment: @NGH Is it better now?

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys that was my fault.  I had a bug in FilterManager.getPossibleAnswers(Filter filter) method.  Basically, at the end of the method, I was setting filter.value to the first element of List unconditionally.  Eg instead of writing

```
if (filter.getValue() == null || filter.getValue().isEmpty()) {
    SelectItem first = answers.get(0);
    filter.setValue((String) first.getValue());
}
```

I just wrote:

```
    SelectItem first = answers.get(0);
    filter.setValue((String) first.getValue());
```

Although filter.value was updating as normal, the value was changing back to default (first element in list) during re-rendering of dataTable component.